# Overflow hidden/ellipsis not working on a CSS Grid

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with a bit of text overflowing on a CSS grid. If the text overflows, I want it to overflow into ellipsis. However it's not working and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

[As you can see here on dev tools it goes past its assigned grid.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4msHi.png)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "nav nav nav nav" "tallarticle largecomic largecomic smallarticle1" "tallarticle largecomic largecomic smallarticle2" "article1 article2 article3 article4";
  grid-gap: 0.2rem;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: aliceblue;
}

.articletext {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <nav>
    Comment
  </nav>
  <div id="tallarticle">
    <h2> Matthew Parris </h2>
    <h1> Our shortage of social housing is a disgrace</h1>
    <div class="articletext">
      (INSERT BIG ARTICLE HERE FOR OVERFLOW)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="largecomic">
    <img id="comicimg" src="comic.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="smallarticle1">smallArticle1</div>
  <div id="smallarticle2">smallArticle2</div>
  <div id="article1">Article1</div>
  <div id="article2">Article2</div>
  <div id="article3">Article3</div>
  <div id="article4">Article4</div>
</div>
```

I tried some of the solutions from previous threads like minmax and min width. But it didn't seem to work.

Comment: You're missing `white-space: nowrap;`.

Comment: Ellipsis will only work if the container has a fixed size. Currently, the container is allowed to grow as much as needed, so the ellipsis rule will never kick in.